# Comparing two strings or objects and getting the difference back

Tags: string, coldfusion, diff, coldfusion-9

I would like to implement a type of version history on my website and I need a way of comparing strings or object keys. For example:

> Original string / object key: The quicker brown fox
>
> Revised string / object key: The quick brown fox
> jumped over the lazy rabbit
>
> Revision: added **jumped over the lazy rabbit** removed **er**

I would like to save only the revision in my history table. I don't really know where to start, so any ideas how to get me going or advice on the approach would be really appreciated.

I am aware of the [find()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e7c.html) function and I suspect it's a prime candidate for use, but I don't know how to visualize it as a solution since it compares strings "wholesale" so to speak.

Comment: As @oragepips pointed out, this is not an easy problem.  For example, in your example, it would be also correct (though maybe less so) to say that " brown fox jumped ov" was added, "brown fox" was removed, and "the lazy rabbit" was added.  Look at 3rd party utilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want a diffing algorithm (I've tagged the question as such), which I highly recommend you **not** try to write yourself. I've tried - and failed - as it's a NP complete problem and not easy to wrap your mind around. Instead, check out [diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/), which has a JavaScript and Java implementation for client ([demo](http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html)) or server side processing. If you need to do HTML differencing look at [daisydiff](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/) instead, albeit be forewarned HTML/XML diffing is truly a painful experience ([see this page for some reasons why](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/Plaintext)).

Probably the grand-daddy of diffing is [GNU diff](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/), which also has a [Java implementation](http://www.bmsi.com/java/) (find "GNU Diff for Java"). This algorithm is more optimized than diff-match-patch (dmp), albeit dmp seems to be improving all the time, so if you need to compare very large strings (e.g. megabytes) the GNU algorithm is probably a better bet.

Comment: orangepips, this is perfect. The only problem is that it's java and I have no clue how to integrate it into a ColdFusion app! If you have any tutorials in mind, please share.

Comment: No, there's a JavaScript version inside the .zip along with an .html file that provides example usage. The demo link I included uses the JavaScript version.

Comment: @Mel, check your CF Web Dev guide, it is super easy to integrate Java into a CF app in general

Answer (score 1):

OK, what about [this](http://www.modernsignal.com/daisydiff_cfc) then?  Not sure if it does plain old strings as you'd like, but it seems to address your concerns about not knowing how to tackle the Java integration bits (since it's already written).  Should at least point you in the write direction.

Comment: Todd, that's great to know. I will look into this. I realized that I don't need to store the only differences. I should just store the entire revised string and use the JS version of diff-match-patch to show the changes on the client side.