# Calculate string difference as range

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out what characters has the user changed in a string. I luckily can assume there's only one, consequent change block.

I've even failed to find where the changed area begins:

```
var originalVal, val; //strings
//The ranges
var original = [0,0];
var new_rang = [0,0];
//Old length, new length
var ol = originalVal.length;
var nl = val.length;
//Find where the change begins (that should be the same for both arrays)

for(var i=0; ; i++) {
  //If end of string was reached or the strings are different
  if((i>=ol||i>=nl) || originalVal[i]!=val[i]) {
    original[0] = new_rang[0] = i;
    //Set these to i too, assuming there was no change
    original[1] = new_rang[1] = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

This totally breaks if there's a row of same characters and user deletes one in the middle:

> mmmmx
>   m<del>m</del>mmx
>   mmm**x**

Script will say that the change occured at 4, where the `x` moved. But in fact, it doesn't even seem to be possible to say **which** `m` was deleted.

I can however tell where the cursor position was at the beginning and where it is in the end. That way it looks more promising, but I still don't know what to do:

> mm|mmx
>   m<del>m</del>|mmx
>   m|mmx

This time I can see which `m` was deleted. But I still don't know how to explain it to a computer.

Comment: Use a library such as https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API. Or http://ejohn.org/files/jsdiff.js. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595108/comparing-two-strings-or-objects-and-getting-the-difference-back/4595225#4595225.

Comment: Can I just ask, is there a particular purpose to knowing _which_ m was removed? If you are going to undo the action it makes no difference if the `m` was inserted at the end of the `m`s, to the user it looks the same, right? So what's the reason you would need to know this?

Comment: I was implementing user script for stack overflow that allows me to paste images over text. This userscript does not block your writing - you can type after pasting the image and when the URL is loaded it's replaced. In that case, position of edits often matters - or at least that's what I remember. Also, I was trying to produce rather general solution applicable to other projects. Here's the script: http://stackapps.com/questions/4999/stackpaste-paste-images-into-the-text-form-instantly

Comment: It sounds like a hassle - is it potentially not easier to just use markdown syntax to denote an image, with that syntax at least you know where the image is and where its supposed to go. You can still replace it once its loaded as now you only need to replace the markdown. I might be wrong, though, I am not 100% clear on it. Interested to see if there is a solution for this but I don't know any.

Comment: @somethinghere I am not sure what you're talking about now. I am using markdown syntax. And I also solved the problem in this question, but the solution is way too robust to be posted as an answer. If you want to talk about this, let's use chat - nobody else will be interested in reading these comments anyway: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97222/calculate-string-difference-as-range

Comment: @TomasZato No, that will be fine, I was just trying to understand your problem, but I'm not the best person for this job (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you might be looking for. Please clarify your question.

```js
var Console = function() {
  this.log = function(msg) {
    debug(msg)
  };
};
var console = new Console();

function diffLengths(longer, shorter) {
  var indexes = [];
  var isTheSame = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < shorter.length; i++) {
    if (shorter[i] != longer[i]) {
      isTheSame = false;
      indexes.push(i);
    }
  };
  if (isTheSame) {
    // The shorter string is exactly the same as the longer string
    // except for the extra characters in the longer string
    indexes.push(shorter.length);
  }
  return indexes;
}

function getDiffRange(first_string, second_string) {
  var indexes = [];
  if (first_string.length > second_string.length) {
    return diffLengths(first_string, second_string);
  } else if (first_string.length < second_string.length) {
    return diffLengths(second_string, first_string);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < first_string.length; i++) {
      if (second_string[i] != first_string[i]) {
        indexes.push(i);
      }
    };
  }
  return indexes;
}

var range = getDiffRange('mmmmx', 'mmmx');
document.getElementById('result-1').innerHTML = range[0] + " - " + range[range.length - 1];

var range = getDiffRange('mmmmx', 'mmmxc');
document.getElementById('result-2').innerHTML = range[0] + " - " + range[range.length - 1];

var range = getDiffRange('mm', 'mmx');
document.getElementById('result-3').innerHTML = range[0] + " - " + range[range.length - 1];
```

```css
table, th, td {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>input</th>
      <th>result</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>'mmmmx', 'mmmx':</td>
      <td id='result-1'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>'mmmmx','mmmxc':</td>
      <td id='result-2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>'mm','mmx':</td>
      <td id='result-3'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Frankly I already solved the problem over a year ago as I needed it to [release this userscript](http://stackapps.com/q/4999/28478). But anyway, what do the number return values from your function mean?

Comment: Cool. Can you post your answer and accept whichever answer is the best. To put this question in a closed status. The `indexes` arrays that get returned are a collection of indexes of where the two strings are different.

Comment: I'll accept this one. I just don't feel like digging into my code anytime soon. I wrote that script in 2 nights streak and it's taken it's toll.